# Pluggable vector processing units in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, pipeline, dataflow, vector-processing

I'm developing some simulation software in Clojure that will need to process lots of vector data (basically originating as offsets into arrays of Java floats, length typically in 10-10000 range). Large numbers of these vectors will need to go through various processing steps - e.g. normalising the vectors, concatenating together two streams of vectors, calculating a moving average etc.

Rather than doing everything in an imperative style, I was hoping to do was create a more functional-style Clojure solution that would do the following:

- allow any vector function to be turned into a **pluggable module**, e.g. (def module-a (make-module some-function))
- allow these modules to be **composed in pipelines**, e.g. (def combined-module (combine-in-series module-a module-b)) would feed the output of module-a into the input of module-b
- allow **auxillary functions** to access state stored within a given module, e.g. (get-moving-average some-moving-average-module), which would need to work even if some-moving-average-module is embedded deep within a combined pipeline
- **hide any boilerplate code** behind the scenes, e.g. allocating sufficiently large temporary arrays for vector calculation.

Does this sound like a sensible approach?

If so, any implementation hints or libraries that might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a functional language, everything is dataflow.  You can use functions as your module concept.

To address each of your use-cases:

- A **pluggagble module** is a Clojure function that takes a single argument that is the state of your data vector.  e.g. `(def module-a some-function)`  To allow for easy extension by modules, I suggest using a Clojure map as your state, where one field is your array of floats.
- **Composing modules** is function composition.  e.g. `(def combined-module (compose module-a module-b)`
- **Auxiliary functions** are accessor functions, extracting state from your data.  e.g. If your data is a Clojure map with a `:moving-average` field, then the keyword `:moving-average` is your accessor function.  State is not stored in modules.
- **Boilerplate code** is hidden in the implementation of your functions, which can be declared anywhere, possibly in another file and namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout conduit. 
http://intensivesystems.net/tutorials/conduit-motive.html